# how to add feedback between client and server in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a simple client - server in Kotlin. There was a problem sending data from the server to the client.
Server: without the "writer" everything works fine and the message comes from the client
Client: without "reader" everything works fine and the server accepts the message.
As soon as I try to add "feedback" to the server and client, everything immediately stops working.

I understand that streams need to be closed, but I cannot understand at what point exactly. I tried many options - it does not work

Server:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val server = ServerSocket(9000)
    val client = server.accept()

    val reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())
    val writer = client.getOutputStream()

    print(reader.nextLine())

    writer.write("Yes".toByteArray())
    writer.flush()
}
```

Client

```
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val client = Socket("192.168.1.8", 9000)
    var writer = client.getOutputStream()
    var reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())

    writer.write("Hi".toByteArray())
    writer.flush()

    print(reader.nextLine())
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you write a newline at the end of "Hi" from the client?  You're calling `reader.nextLine()` which is likely waiting for an EOL before returning.

Comment: Yes. works. The server receives "Hi" but does not send anything in response. Gets after a forced stop of the program. Without it, everything hangs and does not answer

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't send anything in response, or does the client never print anything because the server is also not sending a newline after "Yes"?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything)) So I ask you to help.
So the server sends the line yes and the client should accept it in the last line, doesn't it?
I managed to get the "Connection reset by peer" error after stopping the server first. But I didn't understand anything from it, it would be more logical if it was on the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing newlines in both messages, so the calls to `reader.nextLine()` never return, because the 'next line' hasn't been completely received.  When using `nextLine()` you need to think of the communication protocol as "newline delimited messages".

Note that this also means you can't have newlines in your messages.  If you need more complex messages you may want to consider base 64 encoding the message content.

Working with low level socket protocols can be very challenging, using a higher level protocol like HTTP adds complexity but can also be simpler in some ways.

If you need to use sockets you're likely better off reading a byte at a time and implementing a state machine to process bytes to output, though this will be much more complex than calling `nextLine()`.

The following code works for me:

Server:

```java
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val server = ServerSocket(9000)
    val client = server.accept()

    val reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())
    val writer = client.getOutputStream()

    print(reader.nextLine())

    writer.write("Yes\n".toByteArray()) // <<<<<< Added \n
    writer.flush()
}
```

Client:

```java
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    val client = Socket("127.0.0.1", 9000) // << Also changed to localhost IP.
    var writer = client.getOutputStream()
    var reader = Scanner(client.getInputStream())

    writer.write("Hi\n".toByteArray())  // <<<<< Added \n
    writer.flush()

    print(reader.nextLine())
}
```